# how to read character behind some text

Tags: javascript, jquery

this one a code for read two character behind text "KD-R411ED"

```
var code = data[0].substr(data[0].length - 2);
```

how to read ED character if text like KD-R411H2EDT? i want a new code can combine with code above..please help!!

look this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#tags1").change(function() {
                                                    var barcode;
                                                    barCode=$("#tags1").val();
                                                       var data=barCode.split(" ");
                                                       $("#tags1").val(data[0]);
                                                       $("#tags2").val(data[1]);

                                                    var code = data[0].substr(data[0].length - 2); // suggested by Jan Willem B

                                                      if (code == 'UD') {
                                                                            $('#check1').attr('checked','checked');
                                                    } else {
                                                            if (code == 'ED') {
                                                                            $('#check2').attr('checked','checked');
                                                    }
                                                     }
</script>
```

and this one

```
<input id="check1" type="radio" class="check" name="check" onclick="addtext()" value="U" />U

<input id="check2" type="radio" class="check" name="check" onclick="addtext_1()" value="E" />E
```

Comment: Any more samples? I can't see any patterns here.

Comment: i already editing my question

Comment: Is this jQuery? Tag missing ...

Comment: I don't like the way you asked this question at all. What you need is a clear pattern for your string (which you must know) before you can reliably act/read on it.

Comment: @jAndy..sorry bcoz i'm a beginer and i'm going so mad about this problem..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can control from string like that

```
if (data[0].indexof('UD') > -1)
{
...
}else{

if(data[0].indexof('ED') > -1)
   {

   }
}
```

Comment: how about using regexp..which better?

Comment: if you using complex string types like e-mail or URL, of course RegEx is best. At the otherhand that's a simple 2 char control...

Answer (score 0):

I seems like you are trying to determine if the characters 'ED' or 'UD' are present in a string.  If this is the case, you want to use regular expressions.

Try here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

or here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml

Comment: actually like that..in the same time with separate barcode i want script search some character from string..and then can make radiobutton checked..
could u help me?